# How to combine two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, join, group-by, sum

I have these two tables:

Table 1

```
Date          Name         StudentID          TotalDuration
------------------------------------------------------------
2019-09-30    aA           11111              100
2019-09-30    bB           22222              40
2019-09-30    cC           33333              60
2019-10-07    aA           11111              50
2019-10-07    bB           22222              10
2019-10-07    cC           33333              12
2019-10-07    dD           44444              90
```

It contains data of students who ATTENDED a lecture (hence, does not include those who did not attend.

Table 2

```
StudentID          Surname         FirstName          Group
------------------------------------------------------------
11111              A               a                  1
22222              B               b                  1
33333              C               c                  1
44444              D               d                  2
55555              E               e                  2
66666              F               f                  2
77777              G               g                  3
```

Table2 contains data of ALL students in the class.

Name attribute in Table 1 is combination of surname + first name and TotalDuration is duration of student participation in minutes.

I want to combine these two tables so that it list all the students in the class and their TotalDuration.

I tried `OUTER JOIN` and `UNION ALL`, but can't figure out how I can list all the student, yet shows NULL value for those students who did not attend to the lecture on particular date.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. I'm new to stack overflow and didn't realise it was against the guidelines. I will remember that from now (I'm not sure whether I should edit back now)

Comment: No problem. I rolled back your question to its previous version.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table.] Put your overall goal on hold, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expected & why.

Comment: When you find your misunderstanding or get stuck here it will be a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to aggregate the result by `StudentID` and use a `LEFT JOIN`, as in:

```
select
  a.StudentId,
  a.FirstName,
  a.Surname,
  a.Group,
  sum(b.TotalDuration) as total_duration
from table2 a
left join table1 b on b.StudentId = a.StudentId
group by a.StudentId
```

Note that grouping by `a.FirstName` and `a.Surname` (assuming `StudentId` is the primary key) is optional according to the SQL Standard. I'm not sure SQL server will require it, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could `left join` and `group by`. But since you just need one aggregate computation, a correlated subquery is probably a simpler and more efficient approach (if you have the right index in place - see below):

```
select 
    t2.*,
    (
        select sum(totalduration) 
        from table1 t1 
        where t1.studentid = t2.studentid
    ) totalduration
from table2 t2
```

For performance, consider an index on `table1(studentid, totalduration)`.

Side note: from a database design perspective, column `Name` in `table1` is just not needed; this is redondant information, that complicates maintenance task (what if someone changes the first name of a studend in the other table?). You should remove that column, and rely on the foreign key on `studentid` only.

Comment: That's a great insight. I just used the Name column as an input value that is easy to use and read.